# How does Qt animate the QProgressBar?

Tags: animation, progress-bar, qt5

In some Qt 5 styles (such as Breeze), progress bars which are in indefinite state (minimum == maximum) show an animation.

I want to create my own progress widget which has less visual footprint for use in a status bar, so I looked at the source code of QProgressBar to understand how the animation is implemented.

To my  surprise, I didn’t find any animation code in there. There are no timers. There is no event filter.

How is this animation implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic dust is the [QStyle::polish](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#polish) method. It is invoked on widgets, including the QProgressBar instances.

The breeze style sets up its own animation logic. The progress bars are handled by [Breeze::BusyIndicatorEngine](https://github.com/KDE/breeze/blob/6d2b04fab801f58071fa472be91a40efc7cc7c8c/kstyle/animations/breezebusyindicatorengine.h#L32). It uses a `QPropertyAnimation` to advance its own internal value.

Its `registerWidget` method is invoked from the `polish` implementation of the Breeze style. This in turn saves the widget in an internal map.

When the internal value is updated by the animation, the map is iterated and `update` is invoked on all widgets which are currently being animated (using indirection via QMetaObject).